# Removing Skrollr functionality on mobile screen

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to remove skrollr functionality on mobile screen sizes.

I have the following code in my footer.php which initiates skrollr.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    skrollr.init({
    forceHeight: false
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ + tablets
(function(a) {
     if(/android|avantgo|bada\ ... )
 {
    //Add skrollr mobile on mobile devices.
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="js/skrollr.mobile.min.js"><\/script>');
 }
})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
</script>
```

I have asked around and was told to remove the initialization of skrollr in the footer.php and put code in a separate js file (mobile-fix.js)

so I replaced the script code at the bottom of footer.php with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mobile-fix.js"></script>
```

mobile-fix.js

```
$(function () {
var skrollrInstance;
var onResize = function () {
    var isMobile = $(window).width() <= 767;
    if (!skrollrInstance && !isMobile) {
        skrollrInstance = skrollr.init({
            forceHeight: false
        });
    } else if(skrollrInstance && isMobile) {
        skrollrInstance.destroy();
        skrollrInstance = null;
    }
};
$(window).on('resize', onResize);
onResize();
});
```

I have enquened the mobile-fix.js but when removing the  code from the footer.php skrollr doesn't work on any screen sizes.

Need to initiate skrollr but remove it on screen sizes > 767

Comment: I don't think it should even be that hard.  Less is more.  Look very closely at the classic parallax example, with the kittens.  Check it out on a desktop then check it out on a mobile phone.  Look at the code closely.  Some code is contained within the `<div id="skrollr-body">`  other code is outside of that div.  One set is for desktop, the other for mobile...

Comment: Hmmm. I'm wondering if it possible to chat with you on this stuff?  Sounds like we're in the same place.  (When you want to learn a new activity, say tennis, its no fun to have to play with a pro.  I want to practice with another beginner...)  I hate that this skrollr stuff is hard, I need to start out asking dumb questions that don't meet stackoverflow's format..

Comment: I was able to figure it out on another thread, a bit of code change to make it woe for wordpress, and some misunderstanding on removing script code. But I got her working